# Memory leakage in Java

Tags: java, file-io, out-of-memory

this code is supposed to open a text file, skip the first line, copy the remaining lines to temp variable, clear the file and then rewrite the temp variable into the file.

I am suspecting that this piece of code is generating memory leakage, although I am clearing and closing all objects. Am I missing something here?

This piece of code is called more than 30 times a second.

```
            Scanner scanner_live = new Scanner(file_live);
            ArrayList<String> coll = new ArrayList<String>();
            scanner_live.nextLine();
            while (scanner_live.hasNextLine()) 
                                {
                String line = scanner_live.nextLine();
                coll.add(line);}
            scanner_live.close();

            PrintWriter writer_del = new PrintWriter(file_live);
            writer_del.print("");
            writer_del.close();

            for (String line : coll) {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file_live.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            bufferedWriter.append(line);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.close(); 
            writer.close();
                                    }
            coll.clear();
```

Comment: Can you substantiate your statement `I am suspecting that this piece of code is generating memory leakage`?

Comment: Why are you creating a new `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter` for every line you want to write? Thats just horrible!

Comment: I ran the head dump through the Memory analyzer after getting the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, and I am pretty much sure that leakage is happening here.

Comment: thank you  SebastianH, do you think that this is creating the leakage?

Comment: @user3564557 No, there is (very likely) no memory leak. Just very bad, inefficient coding. Check the answers for lots of useful hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you avoid storing all the lines. Instead you can copy the data as you read it.  You don't actually need to parse each line after the first, you just need to copy the rest of the data.

```
try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_live);
   BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_live+".tmp"))) {
   // skip the first line
   in.readLine();
   char[] buffer = new char[8*1024];
   for(int len; (len = in.read(buffer)) > 0;)
       out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
new File(file_live).delete();
new File(file_live+".tmp").renameTo(new File(file_live));
```

BTW: consuming one line at a time this way is very expensive, esp if the file is large.  If you can I would suggest not re-writing the file at all and instead record separately which line you were up to.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm but more correct.

```
    File file = ...
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        // skip first
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file))){
        for (String line : lines) {
            writer.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also I don't see memory leak if the file is small. But if the file is big it's just because you keep all lines in memory. And JVM memory != all ram on your computer. So JVM could exceed the limit.